# compare two arrays of different length (case of inequality)

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays with different length, for example `A =[ 2 3 11 0 8 ]` and `B=[ 2 6 8]` ( The data are bigger in the real case) and I want to compare them and find elements that verify `abs(A(i)-B(j))> 2` .

Is there any fast function that do that  (such `ismember` but for inequalities) ?

Comment: Fast functions are general fast because of vectorization, that relies in being the same size.

Comment: What is the right answer in this case ? `[0 1 1]`?

Comment: You have `i` and `j` indices. Do you want to compare all pairs of elements (3*5 in your example)? If so, try `[ii, jj] = find(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A(:), B(:).'))>2)`

Comment: Thank you @luis-mendo it solved my problem.

Comment: @houtanb The answer is 15 results ( comparison of each element of A with all elements of B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small function that will check all the possible combinations and send you back the "valid" combination.

```
A = [2 3 11 0 8];
B = [2 6 8];

C = isbigger(A,B,2); %output = the element that verify abs(A-B)>2

function COMB = isbigger(A,B,val)
    [X,Y] = meshgrid(A,B);
    X = X(:);
    Y = Y(:);
    index = abs((X(:)-Y(:)))>val;
    COMB = [X(index),Y(index)];
end
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
C = 

 2     6
 2     8
 3     6
 3     8
11     2
11     6
11     8
 0     6
 0     8
 8     2
```